# Can I Filter Form Data Directly From The URL? (Form Data as Query Parameters) API

Tags: json, api, filter, form-data

I have this URL:

https://www.humanity.com/api/v2/employees?access_token=d397baea8833d805a1a4a474209d6703e5208a06

the response I get is :

{
"status": 1,

"data": [..],

"token": "d397baea8833d805a1a4a474209d6703e5208a06",

"error": null
}

How can I go directly in Data by adding parameters in the URL?

https://www.humanity.com/api/v2/employees?access_token=d397baea8833d805a1a4a474209d6703e5208a06/data

Highly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is a JSON. If you want to access data you would put the response in an object and access data by doing 
    object.data
 which would show all the contents of data.

Comment: Thank you John! However, I wanted to filter the DATA through the URL not from the object.data. (Filter data from the URL not from the Code).